# Argument label (_:) do not match any available overload

Tags: swift, swift4

**Here the code**

```
    func decorate(_ element:UIView, borderSize:Int, borderColor:UIColor, dashed:Bool)
{
    let segmentSize = borderSize * 2
    let border = CAShapeLayer()
    border.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
    border.fillColor = nil
    border.lineWidth = CGFloat(borderSize)

    if (dashed) {
        border.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(segmentSize), segmentSize]
    }

    border.path = UIBezierPath(rect:element.bounds).cgPath
    border.frame = element.bounds

    element.layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

**erroe show in this line**

```
border.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(segmentSize), segmentSize]
```

**Any idea what need to change to resolve this**

Comment: `NSNumber(segmentSize)` to `NSNumber(value: segmentSize)`? Also, the second `segmentSize` in `[NSNumber(segmentSize), segmentSize]` should also be a `NSNumber`, not a `Int`, so do the same.

Comment: Why don't you just ⌃⌘-click on `NSNumber` and check which initializers are available.

Answer (score 0):

### **Problem #1**

The initializer you want to use for `NSNumber` is written as:

```
init(value: Int)
```

In order to leave out the argument label `value:` it would have been written as:

```
init(_ value: Int)
```

Since there is no underscore, you can't leave out the argument label.

### **Problem #2**

`CAShapeLayer` property `lineDashPattern` expects an `[NSNumber]?` which is an optional array of `NSNumber`.  Also note `Array` requires all elements to be the same type because it is a generic collection.

```
let example: [NSNumber]? = [NSNumber(value: 2), NSNumber(value: 2)]
```

> This would set a dash pattern that alternates between a
>   2-user-space-unit-long painted segment and a 2-user-space-unit-long
>   unpainted segment.

### **Solutions**

```
border.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(value: segmentSize), NSNumber(value: segmentSize)]
```

**or**

```
border.lineDashPattern = [segmentSize as NSNumber, segmentSize as NSNumber]
```

**or**

```
let paintedSegmentLength = NSNumber(value: segmentSize)
let unpaintedSegmentLength = NSNumber(value: segmentSize)
border.lineDashPattern = [paintedSegmentLength, unpaintedSegmentLength]
```

**or**

```
border.lineDashPattern = Array(repeatElement(NSNumber(value: segmentSize), count: 2))
```

***References***

[NSNumber Foundation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber)

[Functions in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

[lineDashPatter - CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1521921-linedashpattern)

[Working with Cocoa Frameworks - Foundation - Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

Comment: ... or `border.lineDashPattern = [segmentSize as NSNumber,  segmentSize as NSNumber]`

Comment: @vadian Oh yeah!  I'll add it.

Comment: @vadian Is that technically called Toll-Free bridging?  I can't remember the technical term so I can give an explanation.

Comment: Yes, but in Swift it's called *bridge cast*